# Windows MinGW64 does not export member (static or not) functions defined within class body

Tags: c++, cross-platform, dynamic-linking, mingw-w64

I have updated the code example and added more details since some people say in the comments that this code should not generate any exported symbols period.

---

I also have added some implementation to the methods, but it didn't change nothing in regards of exporting symbols with MinGW and Clang. (Didn't update `objdump` outputs though. Essentially they didn't change much).

---

I came by a very annoying problem with exporting symbols from an executable.

Consider the following code:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

add_executable(app main.cpp)
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS 1)

add_library(lib SHARED main.cpp)
```

```
// main.cpp
class __declspec(dllexport) foo
{
public:
    int bar()
    {
        static int val = 3;
        return ++val;
    }
    static int buz()
    {
        static int val = 814;
        return ++val;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class __declspec(dllexport) foo_t
{
public:
    int bar()
    {
        static int val = 3;
        return ++val;
    }
    static int buz()
    {
        static int val = 814;
        return ++val;
    }
};

template class foo_t<int>;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

### MSVC

When compiled both executable and dll generate `xxx.lib` with exported symbols which can be used for linking.

```
// DUMPBIN.exe /EXPORTS app.lib (exact same as for lib.lib)

Dump of file lib.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  ??4?$foo_t@H@@QEAAAEAV0@$$QEAV0@@Z (public: class foo_t<int> & __cdecl foo_t<int>::operator=(class foo_t<int> &&))
                  ??4?$foo_t@H@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z (public: class foo_t<int> & __cdecl foo_t<int>::operator=(class foo_t<int> const &))
                  ??4foo@@QEAAAEAV0@$$QEAV0@@Z (public: class foo & __cdecl foo::operator=(class foo &&))
                  ??4foo@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z (public: class foo & __cdecl foo::operator=(class foo const &))
                  ?bar@?$foo_t@H@@QEAAXXZ (public: void __cdecl foo_t<int>::bar(void))
                  ?bar@foo@@QEAAXXZ (public: void __cdecl foo::bar(void))
                  ?buz@?$foo_t@H@@SAXXZ (public: static void __cdecl foo_t<int>::buz(void))
                  ?buz@foo@@SAXXZ (public: static void __cdecl foo::buz(void))
```

As can be seen, both `foo` and template `foo_t` methods has been exported.

### Clang

```
Dump of file libapp.dll.a

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  _ZN5foo_tIiE3barEv
                  _ZN5foo_tIiE3buzEv
                  _ZN5foo_tIiEaSERKS0_
```

As it can be seen only `foo_t` methods has been exported **and only due to explicit template instantiation**. If you remove explicit template instantiation there will be no `libapp.dll.a`. However there will be `liblib.dll.a` though with an empty `EXPORTS` section.

### MinGW64

```
Dump of file liblib.dll.a

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  main
                  _ZN5foo_tIiE3buzEv
                  _ZN5foo_tIiE3barEv
```

Like Clang it has exported only explicit template instantiation methods.
But unlike Clang and MSVC **there is no libapp.dll.a** generated for an executable!

```
// objdump -t app.exe

File 
[116](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x00000000000016c0 .text$_ZN5foo_tIiE3barEv
AUX scnlen 0xb nreloc 0 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2
[118](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 1) 0x00000000000016c0 _ZN5foo_tIiE3barEv
AUX tagndx 0 ttlsiz 0x0 lnnos 0 next 0
[120](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   3) (nx 1) 0x00000000000016d0 .text$_ZN5foo_tIiE3buzEv
AUX scnlen 0x7 nreloc 0 nlnno 0 checksum 0x0 assoc 0 comdat 2
[122](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000000016d0 _ZN5foo_tIiE3buzEv
```

The executable itself contains symbols for explicitly instantiated template `foo_t` methods. **Why there is no static library generated for an executable then?**

### Conclusion

1. In all the cases for a dynamic library there are exported symbols in a static library (`libxxx.a` or `xxx.lib`) for explicit class template instantiation. **But MinGW64 does not generate a static library for an executable. Why?**
2. Only MSVC exports symbols for non-template class implicitly inlined methods. **Why? Is it an expected behavior that a cross-platform application could rely on?**
3. Why is there an inconsistency between exporting implicitly inlined in-class implemented methods of a template and non-template classes (non-template are not exported)? **Can a cross-platform application rely on template class methods being exported as a guarantee?**

---

For in-depth understanding of the issue refer to https://github.com/skypjack/entt/issues/719

Comment: `__declspec` is a compiler extension so no two compliers have to do the same thing, or even implement it.

Comment: @RichardCritten in Mingw it is a macro for `__attribute__`

Comment: Which is another compiler extension and may not do the exact same thing.

Comment: Why should the `inline` function be exported? It will be compiled as an `inline` function in the context of compilation unit that includes the header file with that class.

Comment: @harper why not? It has external linkage so other translation units can easily see it no matter was inlined it or not. MSVC and Clang will export them. And on Ubuntu those symbols can also be used. For in-depth understanding of the issue refer to https://github.com/skypjack/entt/issues/719

Comment: If I understand correctly, 1. you are creating static lib 2. You will provide .h and lib to user 3. The issue you mentioned is _only with static_ members. That right?

Comment: @vish not exactly. I am creating an executable and a static lib with exported symbols. Number 2 is correct. 3. The issue is with every in-class defined function (static or not)

Comment: I think this seems as per mingw philosophy: https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/advanced-mingw-dll-topics/ See "Exporting C++ functions and variables from a DLL". That would be really annoying I agree. Simpler method might be use module definition file.

Comment: @vish can you export explicit template instantiations via a `.def` file though?

Comment: It hurts even thinking about it :) But you could `typedef` it and see if it works.

Comment: What is the significance of exporting or not exporting symbols? Do you have a linker error somewhere because of that?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The are no linker errors just because there is an error about non-existent `libapp.dll.a` file. It is crucial to export symbols, because it can be used for type-recovery for something like `std::any` between dynamic boundaries. I added a link to the actual issue in the question.

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to generate separate code or a symbol for an inline function. Some compilers may actually generate symbols sometimes, but I'm not sure why anyone would depend on that. This source file ` struct A { public: A() {} void foo() {} };` doesn't produce any symbols with gcc or clang on (my) Linux.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I suggest you look into `entt` implementation, the link to the issue is in the post. A lot of people use this library (which depends *on that*) and apparently it works. I would be delighted if you joined the discussion on the issue on github

Comment: ... Nor do clang, msys2 gcc, or mingw gcc on windows. So I'm not sure what is the issue here. Inline functions are generally not exported, because no code for them is generated, because no code for them need to be generated in normal circumstances. If you want them generated and exported, mark them for export somehow. If authors of `entt` came to rely on these functions exported automatically and unconditionally, it's their mistake.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. don't you see that the class itself is marked for export?

Comment: You can mark the class for export, and still neither of the three compilers produce any symbols on Windows. You can trivially check it with my example. There is no equivalent of dllexport for classes on Linux.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Idk about your example, but I have explicitly pointed out in the question that when I compile with msvc I do get a static library with exported symbols

Comment: So `entt` relies on behaviour of a single compiler (MSVC) on a single OS(Windows). I'm not sure how this is anybody else's fault.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have updated my question with outputs. I guess you could add an answer regarding exported symbols on Ubuntu and elaborate on the topic. I see that what you said earlier in the comments makes sense. However, please, take a look at an updated question. There is some inconsistency among compilers on windows and implicitly inlined methods of template and non-template classes

Comment: Export libraries are something that I'm very unfamiliar with. It is my understanding that the compiler does not create a symbol if there is no code generated for the function in question. In this case there's nothing to attach the symbol to, so there is nothing to export. There is no requirement to generate code for an inline function, neither in the standard nor in the ABI. So there is an inconsistency between compilers. This is to be expected since this functionality is not covered by any standard.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I added some implementation and also static local variables to the methods. That didn't change anything (compiled with no optimization). I also updated the question.